# ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that have an index `0` and index `1` and in some cases the index `1` will not be exist. I want to bypass it and pass only the index `0` or i want to create it and add value to it.

```
$eq = explode("  -  ", $div->textContent) ;
$p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
$p_part_two_name = $eq[1] ;
```

Comment: dump the `$eq` variable and check if it has the indexes.

Comment: Please add some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI you can use **foreach**

```
foreach ($arr as &$eq) {
   #Here your array value
}
```

you can check count of array

```
$result = count($eq );
if($result==2){
    $p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
    $p_part_two_name = $eq[1] ;
 }
else{
   $p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `$eq[index]` exists or not before sets it as a variable

```
$eq = explode("  -  ", $div->textContent) ;
if(isset($eq[0]))
    $p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
if(isset($eq[1]))
    $p_part_two_name = $eq[1] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

The `array_key_exists()` function checks an array for a specified key, and returns true if the key exists and false if the key does not exist.

```
$eq = explode("  -  ", $div->textContent) ;

if (array_key_exists(1, $eq)) {
    $p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
    $p_part_two_name = $eq[1] ;
} else {
    $p_part_one_name = $eq[0] ;
}
```